# Maximum number of cities a tourist can visit in a blocked grid with 2 walks

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Bear with the length of problem statement:

> A lazy tourist wants to visit as many interesting locations in a city
>   as possible without going one step further than necessary. Starting
>   from his hotel, located in the north-west corner of city, he intends
>   to take a walk to the south-east corner of the city and then walk
>   back. When walking to the south-east corner, he will only walk east or
>   south, and when walking back to the north-west corner, he will only
>   walk north or west. After studying the city map he realizes that the
>   task is not so simple because some areas are blocked. Therefore he has
>   kindly asked you to write a program to solve his problem.
>
> Given the city map (a 2D grid) where the interesting locations and
>   blocked areas are marked, determine the maximum number of interesting
>   locations he can visit. Locations visited twice are only counted once.
>    W and H (2 ≤ W , H ≤ 100)

My Approach to the problem is :

Assume the second traversal as one more traversal from the left hand upper corner.

Now the Walks can be like this:

[image]

But I will assume them to be like this without affecting the result:

[image]

Now we can try and apply Dynamic Programming over here!

`DP[i][j][k]` - represents the maximal number of cities to visit such that in one traversal he is at j and in the second traversal he is at k.

A[i][j] - is +1 if there is a spot at (i,j) , 0 if it doesnt have any , -INFinity  if it is blocked

now for all `k < j` `DP[i][j][k] = INT_MIN`  (By the Image)

Now for `k==j`:

`DP[i][j][k]`=maximum of {

`DP[i][j-1][k]`(Just go right from this state and we will get this recurrence , See you do not add A[i][j] as it will be overcounted) ,

`DP[i-1][j][k]+A[i][k]` (You go directly go down from i-1 th row to both j and i ,Note it is added one time to avoid overcounting)

}
Note : We cannot come from right to the k th element as both j and k are same element because I have assumed that j <=k (From the image)

Now for k>j:

`DP[i][j][k]`=maximum of {

`DP[i][j-1][k]`(Just go right from j-1 and we will get this recurrence ) ,

`DP[i-1][j][k]+A[i][k]+A[i][j]`(Just add the value of both the cells, Coming from i-1 th row)

`DP[i][j][k-1]+A[i][k]`  (Just go right from k-1 to k )

}

Is there some bug in my recurrence !
I have been debugging since Morning and I cannot find any!

If someone wants to see my code and may be correct it or may be suggest something ( Note : Used C++ and  I have overused the ternary operator!)
[Ideone](http://ideone.com/BqpZ9q)

Link to original problem : [Spoj](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TOURIST/)

Answer (score -1):

I think the two traversal solution does not take into account that you will probably revisit places you've been to (and in fact do the same route twice)

Comment: Note that it considers that j<=k , which implies we can have overlapping parts that is why i have that check condition please read my recurrence carefully. Infact See my ideone code I had run it on the case you are mentioning!!